# Adding to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an object in javascript for settings for dataTables.

```
var dataTableSettings = {
  "iDisplayLength": 25,
  "bLengthChange": false,
  "bSortClasses": false,
};
```

I then have an if statement to add another option to the object:

```
if (last_location) {
  dataTableSettings.push(
    "oSearch": {"sSearch": last_location}
  );
}
```

I know that doesn't work because push() doesn't work on objects, how do I add to the object options list?

Comment: `dataTableSettings.oSearch = {"sSearch": last_location}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataTableSettings.oSearch = { "sSearch": lastLocation };
```

Or

```
dataTableSettings['oSearch'] = { "sSearch": lastLocation };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it this way:

```
if (last_location) {
  dataTableSettings.oSearch = {"sSearch": last_location};
}
```

OR

```
if (last_location) {
      dataTableSettings["oSearch"] = {"sSearch": last_location};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this :

```
dataTableSettings.oSearch = {"sSearch": last_location}
```

or this (both are equivalent ):

```
dataTableSettings['oSearch'] = {"sSearch": last_location}
```